# Comma within double quotes not read properly by PropertiesConfiguration

Tags: java, properties, delimiter, apache-commons

I am using class `org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration` for interpreting a property file.

```
PropertiesConfiguration props = new PropertiesConfiguration(path);
String delimiter = props.getString("FIELD_DELIMITER");
```

Everything is fine except one scenario. When the value of `FIELD_DELIMITER` is provided as `","`

```
FIELD_DELIMTIER=","
```

Then, the value of String `delimiter` is obtained as `"`.
Other than this, all other values behaved as expected. For example, if the property is given as:

```
FIELD_DELIMITER="a"
```

then the value of String `delimiter` is obtained as `"a"` (as expected).

I tried to figure out the problem. I realized that compiler takes it as a **comma separated array** , and reads only the first character, i.e. `"` and leaves the rest. The comma that I expect to read is never interpreted at all as the value. This should not happen this way although, as I call the method `getString()` instead of `getStringArray()`.

How can I read `","` then? 
I cannot change the default delimiter for splitting values because I have to read other properties with comma separated values, in the form of `props.getStringArray()`.

Comment: Do not think I have not read the documentation before asking a question here. If you don't believe this happening, try it yourselves. @Tom

Comment: So you claim you have read the documentation and that you still didn't know how to use a "," as part of the String, although that documentation told you how to do that? Or do you want to say that the solution in the documentation didn't work for you? When why haven't you added  that to the question?

Comment: Please read my comment in the answer by Riaan to understand my situation @Tom

Comment: Well, looks like its time to update the question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html), it looks like you can escape the comma.

Example (from the docs):

`# commas may be escaped in tokens
 commas.escaped = Hi\, what'up?`

Comment: You're right, but I cannot actually change the property file, as it will be passed to the code from some other source.

Comment: In that case, you might want to use something other than Apache Commons, if you can't get the owner of the file to modify the property to escape the comma.